# Is it possible to get insight metrics using Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am interested in fetching all data available on this page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/insights/) with Facebook API. Is it possible to get raw data to use with my own graphing tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can query the insights table using either the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/) or [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/).

The insights documentation is not very clear, and in FQL especially, you need to manually ask for data points one period at a time. The FQL documentation is worth reading even if you're using the API since it defines all the different metrics which are available.

Visit the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), get an access token with the Extended Permission `read_insights` and type `/PAGE_ID_OR_USERNAME/insights` into the search box. You'll see a bit of what is available.

You can drill down by adding parameters to the end of the url. For instance `/PAGE_ID_OR_USERNAME/insights/page_fan_adds_unique/day?since=-1 month` gets you a json object with the unique page fan adds each day for about the past month.

You are only able to get insights data for a page where you have admin rights.